# where is unity3d LookAt function internal code implementation located

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to implement my own LookAt Method that's why required to watch the internel implementaion of LookAt and I F12 it for go to defination but i found no implmentiaon of this function as pic depicted.

[image]

where I can find it so that i make copy of it? where it is located and where it is driving.

Comment: you can tools like Resharper, ILspy to see source code

Comment: is there any direct way available to do that? why go to definition is not showing me the implementation completely

Comment: Because you don't have the source code of it.

Comment: @Arek if i dont have the source code then, why it working

Comment: @Mohammad you have a compiled assembly in a dll file. This means Visual Studio doesn't have any source code to show. It could at most show you the assembly code (MSIL). You can however use tools which Ehsan mentioned to get something more human readable.

Comment: @Arek so why does it only showing the name?

Comment: only headers of public members are visible so that you can access them from outside dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the source code if you subscribe to unity pro and pay an additional amount.

See: https://unity3d.com/get-unity

[image: **see this**]